# mysql: Dump table info a file while suppressing cell's multilines

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I'm using MYSQL
how do I Dump table info a file while suppressing cell's multilines

i can use the folowing command to dump table to a file
    select * from tableName
    into outfile 'c:/res.csv'  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

but if there will be cells with multilines it will break the record into sevral lines
how can i avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` then data that consists of multiple lines will be enclosed by a `"`character. It wouldn't stop the records from breaking into several lines but a good csv reader should be able to read your csv file.

If that's not an option I'm afraid the only option is using `REPLACE` to filter out newline characters.